# Any idea why my boolean variables aren't working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, boolean, flash-cs6

It's a simple 'Have Key-Door unlocked/ No Key- Door locked' Boolean thing but whenever I collect the key and try to use the door it still won't open and plays the locked sound, and I can't figure out why.

```
var keyCollected: Boolean = false;
var doorOpen: Boolean = false;

keyclick_btn.buttonMode = true;
keyclick_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, releasekey);

function releasekey(e: Event): void {
    keymc.gotoAndPlay(1);
    keyclick_btn.visible = false;
    keymc.visible = true;
    keyCollected == true;
}

doorhandle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, licklock);

function licklock(e: Event): void {
    if (keyCollected == false) {
        var lockSound: Lock = new Lock();
        lockSound.play();
    }
}
doorhandle_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, open)

function open(e: Event): void {
    if (doorOpen == false) { // if the door hasn't been opened yet
        if (keyCollected == true) {

            doorOpen = true;
            trace("open");
            doorOpenmc.visible = true;
            doorOpenmc.gotoAndPlay(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `releaseKey` function you have an extra `=` in the following statement:

```
 keyCollected == true;
```

Which just evaluates to a boolean and does nothing. If you change it to `keyCollected = true`, the if statement in the `open` function should evaluate to true.